# screen.blit(image) in pygame, image disappears

Tags: python, pygame

I'm trying to blit an image in a pygame window based on one event, a midi input, and then blit another image based on the next event, another midi input. What happens here is that the image pops up just for a second when I press a key on the midi keyboard. I need it to stay in the window, even after I enter another input and blit another image. What happens with this is that each key on my midi keyboard gets recorded as a number (1-88) and added to `NoteList[]` then an image is blit in the window using `h`, an item in `NoteList` as the x coordinate. In my actual pygame the `h` variable will also go through a bunch of functions, I am just trying to figure out this part in a simpler pygame window.

```
going = True
while going:
    screen.fill(white)
    events = event_get()
    NoteList=[]
    for e in events:
        if e.type in [QUIT]:
            going = False
        if e.type in [KEYDOWN]:
            going = False
            events = pygame.event.get()
        if e.type in [pygame.midi.MIDIIN]:
            print(str(e.data1))
            NoteList.append(int(e.data1-20))
    for h in NoteList:
            screen.blit(EthnoteIMG, (int(h), 100))
    pygame.display.update()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to define the `NoteList` outside of the while loop if the notes should persist, otherwise you create a new empty list each iteration.

```
NoteList = []

going = True
while going:
    for e in pygame.event.get():
        if e.type == pygame.QUIT:
            going = False
        elif e.type == pygame.midi.MIDIIN:
            print(str(e.data1))
            NoteList.append(int(e.data1-20))

    screen.fill(white)

    for h in NoteList:
        screen.blit(EthnoteIMG, (int(h), 100))

    pygame.display.update()
```

---

You can use the [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate) function to shift the position:

```
for g, h in enumerate(NoteList):
    screen.blit(EthnoteIMG, (g*12, int(h)))
```

Comment: I also recommend to add a clock `clock = pygame.time.Clock()` and then limit the frame rate by calling `clock.tick(30) # or 60` in the while loop.

Comment: Ok thanks. Do you know how I would do this inside of a while loop like this: g=0     while g>8:    g+=1    screen.blit(IMG, (g*12), int(h)), where it only goes through the loop once each time i input something via MIDI

Comment: I've added a paragraph to the answer. Is that what you want?

Comment: What I'm trying to do is create an object with 4 variables attached to it, Note(x,y,z,d), and then run a function on it, Note.ExNote() which blits an image into the window. I have 3 while loops inside of eachother to determine 3 variables and the midi input decides the 4th. Everytime I input another note, one of the other 3 variables will change slightly based on the while loop like (y+=1) and so I can input notes and they are printed onto the sheet music for me. Only problem is that I input one note and it runs through all the loops and prints it out all over the sheet music

Answer (score 0):

I belive that the problem is that you fill the screen every time the while loop runs but you just blit that image on the screen when the event occurs...

Try this:

```
screen.fill(white)
going = True
while going:
    events = event_get()
    NoteList=[]
    for e in events:
        if e.type in [QUIT]:
            going = False
        if e.type in [KEYDOWN]:
            going = False
            events = pygame.event.get()
        if e.type in [pygame.midi.MIDIIN]:
            print(str(e.data1))
            NoteList.append(int(e.data1-20))
    for h in NoteList:
        screen.fill(white)
        screen.blit(EthnoteIMG, (int(h), 100))
    pygame.display.update()
```